# Outbound messaging wsdl

Tags: integration

In Outbound messaging WSDL we have :-

element name="Notification" maxOccurs="100" type="tns:ContactNotification"

So as per my understanding the  indicator specifies the maximum number of times an element can occur.

So, the  specifies the notification can occur 100 times for particular object in an outbound message on single go.

My confusion is -  what happens if we do bulk upload ( say 250 records ) on an object. what happens to the outbound message? Will it have all the 250 notifications in one message or will there be 250 separate messages sent to end point?

I would really appreciate if some one could help me on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sara, the [SOAP API Developer's Guide](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_om_outboundmessaging_notifications.htm) implies that the messages will be grouped together when possible for efficiency's sake. This means when you load 250 records in a single operation, you should expect three outbound messages to be sent. The first two messages would each contain 100 notifications, and the third message would contain the remaining 50 notifications.

You can verify this behavior fairly easily using a tool like [RequestBin](http://requestb.in) and importing 250 leads using the Data Loader or the Import Wizard.

Comment: But the final fifty may be queued until fifty more come in, if it's within a short period. They need not be in the same logical transaction.